# Making my first calculator in C# and I'm stuck

Tags: c#, calculator

Just getting into C# and programming in general, i'm making a calculator with the windows form app project template. i'm trying to make my calculator work like a regular one does where if you press 1+1 and then + again it shows the sum of the 1+1 and waits for the next number input to add to that.

My code for hitting any of the number buttons is `tb1.Text = tb1.Text + "the number being pressed"`

I have defined 3 variables so far  `int num1 = 0; int num2 = 0; int result;`

my code for the onclick of the "+" button is as follows

```
        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Add
            if (num1 == 0)
            {
                num1 = Convert.ToInt32(tb1.Text);
                tb1.Clear();
            }
            else
            {
                num2 = Convert.ToInt32(tb1.Text);
                result = num1 + num2;
                tb1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
                num1 = result;
                tb1.Clear();
                tb2.Text = Convert.ToString(num1);
                tb3.Text = Convert.ToString(num2);
            }
        }
```

this code works and i can see it working because i have debugging text boxes(tb2 and tb3) and tb2 shows
me that num1 is = to the sum of the numbers i am adding together. i am able to add two numbers and then
add another number to that, so on. but id like the sum of the first two numbers to be displayed in tb1
when i hit the + sign again to add another number to it. i figured i would do that by adding

```
tb1.Text = Convert.ToString(num1);
```

before my if statement (right below the //Add comment) in the addition button click method. this instead makes nothing show up in the
debug tb2 textbox and doesn't fix my problem and im unsure why. even if i parse it back to an int right
after this new line nothing changes. if more or clearer information is needed, i will oblige

Comment: https://github.com/juliusfriedman/net7mma_core/blob/master/Concepts/Classes/Number.cs

Answer (score 0):

To explain the `this instead makes nothing show up in the debug tb2 textbox and doesn't fix my problem and im unsure why`:

When you add `tb1.Text = Convert.ToString(num1);` before the first `if` statement, you end up with the following flow:

1. Program loads. `num1` is 0, `tb1.Text` is empty
2. User enters 5 in `tb1`
3. `button1_Click` is called

   1. `tb1.Text` is set to `num1` (0)
   2. Enter `if (num1 == 0)` block
   3. `num1` is set to `tb1.Text` (0)
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3

With this, you end up endlessly setting `num1` to 0 and never get to the `else` block to set `tb2.Text`.

---

Rather than resetting the `tb1.Text` value at the beginning of `button11_Click`, you might just need to remove the `tb1.Clear();` in the `else` block. That statement doesn't make much sense considering it's being called just after `tb1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);`. So the code would end up being:

```cs
//Add
if (num1 == 0)
{
    num1 = Convert.ToInt32(tb1.Text);
    tb1.Clear();
}
else
{
    num2 = Convert.ToInt32(tb1.Text);
    result = num1 + num2;
    tb1.Text = Convert.ToString(result);
    num1 = result;
    tb2.Text = Convert.ToString(num1);
    tb3.Text = Convert.ToString(num2);
}
```